# How do I make Bootstrap Date & Time picker open down instead on top

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

The Date and Time menu is the 3rd one on this list, yet it opens up at the very top.
How do I make this appear right at the bottom of the Date and Time Picker form?

````
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/form.css" />

    <link href="css/Form.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script href="js/Form.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control js-datetimepicker"
        placeholder="When do you leave?"
        id="datetimepicker"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
      />
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/nl-be.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/form.js"></script>


```
````

Comment: Docs: [widgetPositioning](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetpositioning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try widget positioning:

```
$(function () {
    $('#yourpicker').datetimepicker({
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'right',
            vertical: 'bottom'
        }
    });
});
```

Docs [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetpositioning)